# Gay nightlife in Berlin

Tags: berlin, nightlife, lgbt

Soon, I will be visiting Berlin with a gay friend.  It would be nice to take him to some gay or gay friendly bars and clubs.  We won't be trying to hook up, just enjoy the ambience and maybe a show.

We are both male and neither of us are young so we don't want very loud, high energy venues such as Techno.

I am not gay myself but I have visited many other gay bars and clubs with this friend and other friends.  I know how to behave appropriately (basically just be a nice person) so, unless straights are forbidden, that should not be a problem.

Additions:

Venues do not need to be specifically gay; they may welcome a range of sexual orientations.

I am not expecting recommendations for specific bars and clubs but is there an area which we should explore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berlin is a very LBGTQ+ friendly city, so you should have a great time. It's probably the second most gay friendly city I have ever been in (other than Provincetown, MA, USA), but, of course, individual experiences vary.

A simple Google Search will give you a LOT of good resources. Start here:

- https://www.visitberlin.de/en/gay-berlin-lgbtq-guide-berlin
- https://www.travelgay.com/destination/gay-germany/gay-berlin
- https://nomadicboys.com/berlin-gay-area-travel-guide/

Comment: Note that while I have no idea of the quality of those resources for Berlin, many such guides are often severely outdated (especially in the smaller cities). It’s always good to cross-check the info.

Comment: To explore, start in a large corner Café on the Motzstraße west of Nollendorfplatz, open daily from 08:00 to midnight. There you can gather information  or obtain tips from others based on your interests.

Comment: @jcaron: the first link I posted is maintained by the city itself and it's definitely up to date.

Comment: Virtually a link only answer...